# How to Select first 10 records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my database have 100 records but i want only first 10 records in descending order not for whole database in descending order.

Ex:
Database:Records

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6,,7,8,9,10,11,12....................100.
```

First 10 Records:

```
10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY * ASC LIMIT 10) 
ORDER BY * DESC ;
```

Comment: $sqlsl="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM newmessage ORDER BY inboxid ASC LIMIT 3) ORDER BY inboxid DESC";Thanks for reply , code not work Server send Error message :  Error: (1248) Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Change `... LIMIT 10) ORDER BY ...` to `... LIMIT 10) AS MySubquery ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT x FROM table ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY x DESC
```

The `SELECT` in parentheses selects the first 10 records (by ascending `x`) and the outer `SELECT` sorts them in the order you want.

Answer (score 7):

Use `LIMIT`. See the [mySQL manual on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

For example:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY ID LIMIT 0,10
```

the turning around of the results like you show is then probably best done in PHP using [`array_reverse()`](http://www.php.net/array_reverse), I can't think of a easy mySQL way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIMIT`. See the mySQL manual on SELECT

**For example:**

```
SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY ID LIMIT 0,10
```

The turning around of the results like you show is then probably best done in PHP using `array_reverse()`, I can't think of a easy MySQL way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).